# Conversion failed when converting varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My stored procedure accepts one parameter, and it is a datetime. If no parameter is passed, I default it to the `getdate()` function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myexport]
(
    @start datetime = null
)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    set @start = isnull(@start, getdate())
```

When I run the stored procedure with no parameters, my results are correct. When I pass it a date parameter, I get the following error:

```
exec myexport '2013-04-22 00:00:00:00'

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure myexport, line 16
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '(-) 0mms' to data type int.
```

Here is the context of my @start date:

```
select
    count(distinct pid),
    'Inpatient Hosp'
from
    form_names fn
        inner join form_items fi on fn.id = fi.form_name
        inner join form_records fr on fn.id = fr.form_name
        left outer join form_answers fa on fi.id = fa.form_item and fa.form_record = fr.id
where
    fn.name like '%Transfer of Health Information%'
    and dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, fr.date)) = dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, @start))
    and fi.text like '%date of return%'
    and fa.id is NULL
```

EDIT -

My stored procedure id rather large with a lot of sub queries, but I think I found the offending query:

```
select
    count(*),
    'PPD +'
from
    form_records fr
        inner join form_names fn on fn.id = fr.form_Name
        inner join form_items fi on fn.id = fi.form_name
        inner join form_answers fa on fr.id = fa.form_record
            and fa.form_item = fi.id
where
    fn.id = 3
    and fa.form_item = 30
    and fa.text not like '%neg%'
    and dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, fa.entered_date)) = dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, @start))
    and CAST(fa.text AS INT) >= 10
```

When I manually run this query with `getdate()`, my results are correct, but when I run it with `'2013-04-22 00:00:'00`, I get the error.

The data type of `fa.entered_date` is a `datetime`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That error looks like it is caused by your data, and not your parameter.  I think that you've left out something important here, so please provide a more complete copy of the procedure.

Comment: RBarryYoung - I have added, what I think, is the offending portion of the query.

Comment: Seems like you have data in `fa.text` that cannot be converted to an `INT`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you have answered my question. Could you please add this as an answer.

Comment: You have your answer. Let's let the close/delete process take its course.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're adding too many 00's.

Try this: `exec myexport '2013-04-22 00:00:00'`

Comment: Thanks for the response Jack, but that still fails. I've tried it with just the date, also.

Comment: I don't think you need to do this: start datetime = null.  I think you can just @start DATETTIME

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you trying to do on last query.  However, Syntax should be

```
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
```

You have

```
dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, @start))
```

DATEDIFF returns **INT**

You need change your query

Comment: Dates can be represented as integers.  Today is 41391

Comment: Right but his DATEDIFF is returning the number of days differnece, not a date represented as an integer.

Comment: @Aushin. You are right. However, I don't think that what OP want in the query. Personally, I never see anyone use integers as datetime for DATEADD function. At lease, it's bad practices.

Comment: Actually, this `dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, @start))` is a well known and extremely fast way to remove the time from a datetime value, just leaving the date.

Comment: @RBarryYoung not when you do it to the column - it negates an index (CONVERT(DATE) would not, though.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand  Really? I did not know that, I thought CONVERTs always negated the indexes.  Sadly it's SQL Server 2005, so IIRC, there's no CONVERT(DATE) yet.

Comment: @RBarryYoung that's the only exception I know of. Oh and 2005 vs. 2008: that's why I said *would not* :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good to know. Aside: is there any master list of all of the exceptions to the "*expressions negate indexes*" rule?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I don't know of any such list. Again, CONVERT(DATE is the only exception I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Using an unambiguous format to specify the date may help here. Use e.g.

```
'20130422'
```

or

```
'2013-04-22T10:57:33.007'
```

Anything else can run into ambiguities; e.g. in some circumstances, SQL Server will interpret `2013-04-22` or `2013-04-22 10:57:33.007` as being dates from the 4th of the 22nd month and fail in conversion.

---

Also, for your query, I'd run it as:

```
and fr.date> = @start and fr.date < DATEADD(day,1,@start)
```

Having set `@start` before the query runs:

```
set @start = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,@start),0)
```

This means that if there's an index that includes `fr.date`, there's at least a possibility that the index can be used.